# Scrape E-Mails using IMAP without Exceeding Bandwidth

Tags: php, email, imap, bandwidth

I have the following code which works great to do what it is meant to do.  It scrapes bodys of all e-mails in the inbox at an e-mail address using IMAP and retrieves the unique code sent inside the body and stores it in a database with the amount paid.  I'm hoping to make it so when a user purchases something they can send an Interac e-transfer and then enter the code that both of us receive via e-mail in the website and it will apply the credit of the e-transfer to their account/purchase.

However; after setting it up on a cron job to cycle every few minutes so the content in the database stays fresh it eventually exceeds the bandwidth for the account within a day or so (not positive on how long it took but it didn't take long).  Now, like I said the code works it's just very resource intensive apparently.

I do not pipe the script because the e-mail account has already been set up a while ago and we do use the account for other e-transfers which I review manually for other transactions.

1. Is there anyway to clean it up so it works the same but uses less resources/bandwidth?
2. Would it be better to run it when a user enters their payment code?  Depending on the number of users running it this could also lead to bandwidth troubles.
3. Is there any improvements or what ideas do you have?

```php
        define("MAX_EMAIL_COUNT", $_POST['maxcount']);
    
        /* took from https://gist.github.com/agarzon/3123118 */
        function extractEmail($content) {
            $regexp = '/([a-z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-z0-9]{2,4})+/i';
            preg_match_all($regexp, $content, $m);
            return isset($m[0]) ? $m[0] : array ();
        }
    
        function getAddressText(&$emailList, &$nameList, $addressObject) { 
            $emailList = '';
            $nameList = '';
            foreach ($addressObject as $object) {
                $emailList .= ';';
                if (isset($object->personal)) { 
                     $emailList .= $object->personal;
                } 
                $nameList .= ';';
                if (isset($object->mailbox) && isset($object->host)) { 
                    $nameList .= $object->mailbox . "@" . $object->host;
                }    
            }    
            $emailList = ltrim($emailList, ';');
            $nameList = ltrim($nameList, ';');
        } 
    
        function processMessage($mbox, $messageNumber) { 
            global $db;
            // get imap_fetch header and put single lines into array
            $header = imap_rfc822_parse_headers(imap_fetchheader($mbox, $messageNumber));
    
            $timestamp = strtotime($header->Date);
    
            $fromEmailList = '';
            $fromNameList = '';
            if (isset($header->from)) { 
                getAddressText($fromEmailList, $fromNameList, $header->from); 
            }
            $toEmailList = '';
            $toNameList = '';
            if (isset($header->to)) {
                getAddressText($toEmailList, $toNameList, $header->to); 
            } 
            $body = imap_fetchbody($mbox, $messageNumber, 1);
            
            //echo "<pre>".print_r($body,true)."</pre>";
            
            /* Find Reference Number */
            //echo "<pre style='background-color: #A2A2A2; border: 1px solid black'>$body</pre>";
            $searchfor = 'Reference Number';
            
            // get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
            $contents = $body;
            // escape special characters in the query
            $pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
            // finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
            $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
            // search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
            
            if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
               $reference = trim(str_replace('Reference Number : ','',$matches[0][0]));
            }
            else{
            }
            /* Find Amount Paid */
            //echo "<pre style='background-color: #A2A2A2; border: 1px solid black'>$body</pre>";
            $searchfor = 'has sent you a money transfer for the amount of';
            
            // get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
            $contents = $body;
            // escape special characters in the query
            $pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
            // finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
            $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
            // search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
            
            if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
                $amount = trim(preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", "",$matches[0][0]),'.');          
            }
            else{
            }
            
        
            $bodyEmailList = implode(';', extractEmail($body));
            // Delete all messages older than one year (31557600 seconds).  Divide it by two for six months.
            if($timestamp < time()-31557600) {
                if(imap_delete($mbox,$messageNumber)) {
                    /*echo "<strong>";
                    print_r($messageNumber . ' , ' . date("F j, Y g:i A",$timestamp).' , ' . 'Deleted' . "\n");
                    echo "</strong>";*/
                }
            }
            else {
                if(!empty($reference) && !empty($amount)) {
                    if($fromNameList == "catch@payments.interac.ca" && $toNameList!='etransfers@example.com') {
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM `".$db->prefix."payments_etransfer` WHERE `reference_id` = '".$reference."'";
                        
                        $select = $db->select($query);
                        if($db->num_rows($select) > 0) {
                            
                        }
                        else {
                        
                            $do = $db->insert_sql("INSERT INTO `".$db->prefix."payments_etransfer` SET
                            `email_id` = '".$messageNumber."',
                            `timestamp` = '".$timestamp."',
                            `reference_id` = '".$reference."',
                            `amount` = '".$amount."',
                            `sender` = '".$fromEmailList."'");
                            
                            if($do) {
                            }
                            else {
                                echo "Error<br><blockquote><pre>";
                            
                                
                                print_r($messageNumber . ',' . $timestamp. ',' . $reference . ',$' . $amount .
                                   ',' . $fromEmailList . ',' . $fromNameList 
                                    . ',' . $toEmailList . ',' . $toNameList 
                                    . ',' . $bodyEmailList . "\n"
                                );
                                echo "</pre></blockquote>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    
        // imap_timeout(IMAP_OPENTIMEOUT, 300);
    
        // Open pop mailbox
        if (!$mbox = imap_open($_POST['mailbox'], $_POST['login'], $_POST['password'])) {
          die('Cannot connect/check pop mail! Exiting');
        }
    
        if ($hdr = imap_check($mbox)) {
          $msgCount = $hdr->Nmsgs;
        } else {
          echo "Failed to get mail";
          exit;
        }
    
      /*  echo "<pre>";
        echo 'emails count=' . $msgCount . "\n\n\n";
        echo "record number,from emails list,from names list,to emails list, to names list,extracted from body\n";
    */
        /* might improve performance according to
           http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-headerinfo.php#98809 
           imap_headers($mbox);
        */
    
        for ($X = $msgCount; $X > 0; $X--) {
            if($X > 0) {
                processMessage($mbox, $X);
            }
            
        } 
        /*echo "</pre>";*/
        imap_expunge($mbox);
        imap_close($mbox);
    /*
```

Comment: What problem is it - network bandwidth or CPU utilisation?  Also it may be a certain amount of experimenting with various bits of code.  It may be worth trying https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if the code works as that is more about trying to improve the quality of code.

Comment: is it just me, or is that a huge security risk? Anyone could send an email to that email address, formatted like a transfer and receive credit in whatever system this feeds into, right?

Comment: @Nigel: It is the bandwidth I'm having an issue with as it exceeds my limit in a short time and closes the website.

Comment: @Erik:  I have thought about that and yes at the moment there is that risk.